# Telerik RadMenu Click To Open and Close when clicked to next page

Tags: javascript, c#, telerik, radmenu

Hi im having problem with my radmenu. I want it to click to open and not open as you hover. I have set the clicktoopen = "true" already. Now the problem is when i click, it navigate to the respective requested page but the menu doesn't close.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function OnClientItemClicking(sender, args) {
         if (args.get_item().get_isOpen() == true) {
            args.set_cancel(true);
            args.get_item().close();

         }
         else {
         }
     }

 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientMouseOverHandler(sender, eventArgs) {
        if (eventArgs.get_item().get_parent() == sender) {
            sender.set_clicked(false);
        }
    }

   function onClientItemClicked(sender, args) {
   }
      </script>
```

Comment: <telerik:RadMenu ID="menuUser" runat="server" ClickToOpen="True" OnClientMouseOver="OnClientMouseOverHandler" OnClientItemClicking ="OnClientItemClicking" OnClientItemClicked ="onClientItemClicked" Style="top: 0px; left: 0px"
                        EnableAutoScroll="True" AutoPostBack = "true" Width="100%" AutoScrollMinimumHeight="100" Height="25px" OnItemDataBound="menuUser_ItemDataBound">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Target="ContentPane"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadMenu>

Comment: whatever you have posted in the comment section, post it in the question and format it properly for good code readability

Comment: I inserted already but its not coming out hence i place it in the comment